# How to filter find duplicate and show row with same field using sqlite code?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am learning the SQL code and don't know how to find the duplicate row and show it out.
Here is the table

| person_no | name | birthday |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | John | 01/01/2000 |
| 02 | John | 15/03/2000 |
| 03 | Marry | 21/06/2000 |
| 04 | Peter | 23/12/2000 |
| 05 | Jerry | 12/07/2000 |

The person_no is unique for everyone, but the name may be same, anyway to find the people with same name but different person_no ?

Sorry if my question bothers you

Comment: Sample table data is great, but you should also _specify_ the expected result.

Comment: My apologies. The expected result is list all the personal detail of everyone who shares the same name with someone

Comment: Is it just the `group by` function you are asking about ? [explained here](https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-group-by/)

Comment: I think I am looking for a compare function between rows? And list the compare result, in which, the same in person's name

Comment: You should also _specify_ the expected result, not describe it.

Comment: Thanks for all the help! 
To people looking for similar questions, the hint is subquery, HAVING and GROUP BY

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from person_table
join(
    select name from person_table
    group by name
    having count(person_no) > 1
) temp on person_table.name = temp.name;
```

First, find out the duplicate names from the subquery. Then using an inner join, find the rows in the table that have the names from the subquery result.

Without join:

```
select * from person_table
where name in (
    select name from person_table
    group by name
    having count(person_no) > 1
)
```

This should also give you the rows with duplicate values is the column *name*, without using join.

Comment: Join is not necessary for my question, but thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Edited the answer to include another way. Hope that helps